# How to increase margin of a font awesome image

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4

The image is in a h1 editing margin of h1 only edits margin-left increases the margin on the left of the image. trying to increase margin of i element does nothing either on i element does nothing either.

```
  <h1 class="display-4"><i class="fas fa-camera-retro"></i>The Image Gallery</h1>
           <p> A bunch of beautiful images that I didn't take</p>
```

[image]

I want to increase the space between the camera icon and the text.

Comment: Please Share Any url or more details about this.

Comment: Have you tried by adding another class "fa-fw" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just apply the `mr-3` class to the icon like so:

```html
<h1 class="display-4"><i class="fas fa-camera-retro mr-3"></i>The Image Gallery</h1>
<p> A bunch of beautiful images that I didn't take</p>
```

`mr-3` means "margin-right 3 units".

By default, Bootstrap gives you 5 options for margin and padding classes i.e. choose a number between 1 and 5. And of course, the number 0 will zero things out.

Answer (score 4):

Increasing the margin of `i` element works fine:

```css
i {margin-right:20px}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h1 class="display-4"><i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i>The Image Gallery</h1>
           <p> A bunch of beautiful images that I didn't take</p>
```

You might inspect the element and find what exactly overrides your style.
But the best way is to post a question at SO, sure.